# Possible to transfer save from PS3 to PC?

Tags: pc, ps3, dark-souls

Ok. Well, long story short.

Have a PS3, got Dark Souls on it. End of year sale 2014 on Steam. Bought Dark Souls PTDE on it cheap, got a computer upgrade, and here I am.

I have already completed 3/4 of the game on the PS3, and honestly don't have the energy to start **all** over again, farming for another 3 hours, and acquiring **everything** I have, all over again.

Is it possible to somehow transfer PS3 save files to PC and play the game with them?

The only information I can find is 3+ years old which is all about Games for Windows Live making life harder...

GFWL dropped Dark Souls support, and is now supported by Steamworks, so that doesn't come into play anymore. So is there a way, 4 years later?

Comment: I can't find much information about it, but there have been games before where it was possible. I guess there's only one way to find out - try it! You should be able to grab your saved games with a USB stick.

Comment: @IvoCoumans Mmmm... To be honest, I haven't actually tried yet... Alright! Will do it now.

Comment: @IvoCoumans *strange noises* Mmmm.. Arhhh.. Guuu... *strange noises* Nope! Only place it allows me to copy it to is PS+... I tested it with other game saves such as Little Big Planet to make sure I wasn't hallucinating. Definitely a feature they blocked...

Comment: I'm not sure if they'll work on PC afterwards (probably not), but it says here that transferring by USB should be possible: http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-General/How-to-Transfer-Saves-to-another-PS3/td-p/31057294, it says: `You just need a USB thumb drive formatted as FAT to use for backups. Use Saved Data Utility to make individual backups of save games.`

Comment: @IvoCoumans OK, thanks. Ill try again tomorrow using the following suggestion. (Getting a little late, and I got things on tomorrow) Get back to me if you find anything else out. I ***really*** appreciate it.

Comment: I will be really super surprised if there's a way to do this. If helps any, you'll probably be able to play through the first 3/4 of the game much faster the second time around, now that you know what you're doing.

Comment: @cbirdsong That wasn't my first time. It was my fifth. I just completed the rest, got bored and restarted. This time I just felt like I had to keep it, and thus didn't want to start **for the sixth time**...

Comment: No offense, mate, but if you're farming for 3 hours on your fifth playthrough then you should definitely consider redoing your strategy. 3 hours is my average time to beat the entire game after five playthroughs, not to mention that even when I did play it the first time I didn't farm. Not trying to brag here, but I seriously doubt this will work for you, so I suggest you consider other options.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc Mmmm... Well, in the meantime, I'm nearly halfway on the PC, but it's just because I have become attached to my save, don't want to loose it. :(

Comment: @FinnRayment Did you ever get anywhere with this? It seems that it's difficult to copy PS3 Dark Souls saves to a thumb drive (or anywhere else).

Answer (score 2):

To officially answer this, as it currently stands, the answer is **no, it's not possible.**

Or at least far more effort than it's worth. While some arguments go with the fact that the "Playstation supports Linux", short of re-writing Linux to read an NTFS harddrive carrying (god-knows-what) file types and allowing you to play them in some kind of jerry-rigged emulator, I'd say that's a long shot.

Most sources I have found on this topic are a few years old by now (and primarily on the topic of DkS2, not DkS1), but I still doubt the situation has changed.

- [Steam Support Forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2899635)
- [GameSpot Forums](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/pc-mac-linux-society-1000004/converting-ps3-save-files-for-use-with-pc-games-26940210/)
- [GameFAQs Forums](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/893785-dark-souls-ii-scholar-of-the-first-sin/70677375)
- [Giant Bomb Forums](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/893785-dark-souls-ii-scholar-of-the-first-sin/70677375)

However, I have found [this](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3203440) forum post covering the method to change your Fallout 3 save to PC; but again, I'm not sure if this is relevant to this case.